# The feeling of pissed off combined with enviousness

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I would like to know whether there is a word in English that can express the feeling of being pissed off combined with enviousness. I have searched in dictionaries for synonyms of both, but I couldn’t find any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps **jealous**?

In discussing the usage differences between *envy* and *jealousy*, NOAD includes a note that reads:

> *Jealous* may refer to a strong feeling of envy, or it may imply an intense effort to hold on to what one possesses; **it is often associated with distrust, suspicion, anger, and other negative emotions**. [emphasis added]

Answer (score 1):

You may use any of these words -

> Covetous, envious or jealous as described as close synonyms [here](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/jealous/).

Now coming to your concern with pissed off PLUS 'enviousness'. [Wikipedia describes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jealousy)

> Popular culture uses the word **jealousy as a synonym for envy (so when you are envious, you are probably pissed off as well!**). Many dictionary definitions include a reference to envy or envious feelings. In fact, the overlapping use of jealousy and envy has a long history.

Perhaps the overlapping use of jealousy and envy occurs because people can experience both at the same time.

In other words, getting pissed off *(frustrated, annoyed or disturbed)* depends on the degree of your enviousness and is more psychological.

Comment: @J.R., both of your answers lead to the same word and have helped me a lot. I never thought of “jealousy” since in my first language it has the main meaning of “sexual jealousy” and rarely has other usage.
Meanwhile, I have continued my search and found two more words: “grudge and pique” that, maybe can go along with jealousy to express the feeling I was asking in my question.
Regarding these two words I have noticed the expressions: “to bear a grudge against someone” and “to take pique against someone”. I wonder whether the words “bear” and “take” might be interchangeable in this context.

Comment: @LucianSava - _bear a grudge_ is fine (sometimes also worded as _nurse a grudge_). As for _pique_, I wouldn't use it as you've suggested here; I'd say, "I was piqued **at** Joe," or maybe, "I was piqued **with** Joe," but not, "I took pique **against** Joe," although we don't hear _piqued_ used in that context all that often, and, truthfully, I'd avoid that one altogether.